# How to make bootstrap menu collapse button work on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bootstrap button that works on everything but Safari iOS. I have already added the href attribute like some other forums suggested, and both cursor: pointer and z-index: 3000 to my button. Some other places suggested using a data-parent instead of data-parent, but that only made it not work in other browsers as well.

Here's the code for my button:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" href="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="cursor: pointer; z-index: 3000;">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

CSS for .navbar-toggle is as follows:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 11px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the bootstrap example work when using your mobile?

Comment: <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> You dont need any other css then the existing bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

```
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
```